# It 140 Project two help: Can not pick up items in game and messages when entering the dining room won't populate

Tags: python, list, function

Here is my current code using python. as I said I am having trouble getting the code to allow me to pick up items as well as getting it to display the win/lose conditions when entering the dining room. Thanks for the help!

import sys

```
# Define the game rooms
rooms = {
    'Break Room': {'south': 'Back Room'},
    'Back Room': {'north': 'Break Room', 'west': 'Kitchen'},
    'Kitchen': {'south': 'Office', 'west': 'Dining Room', 'north': 'Pantry', 'east': 'Back Room'},
    'Office': {'east': 'Outside', 'north': 'Kitchen'},
    'Outside': {'west': 'Office'},
    'Pantry': {'east': 'Fridge', 'south': 'Kitchen'},
    'Fridge': {'west': 'Pantry'},
    'Dining Room': {'east': 'Kitchen'}
}

# Define the items in each room
room_items = {
    'Back Room': 'Chef’s Hat',
    'Kitchen': 'Chef’s Knives',
    'Office': 'Recipe',
    'Outside': 'Remy',
    'Pantry': 'Spices',
    'Fridge': 'Ingredients'
}

# Define the remaining items needed to complete the game
remaining_items = ['Chef’s Hat', 'Chef’s Knives', 'Recipe', 'Remy', 'Spices', 'Ingredients']

# Initialize player's inventory
inventory = []

# Game introduction
print("With help from his friend, Remy, Linguini has become popular for his new ratatouille dish.")
print("An influential Food Critic, Anton Ego, has come to the restaurant to see for himself.")
print("Collect 6 items to wow the food critic or receive a negative review from Anton Ego!\n")
print("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
print("Directions: to move between rooms type 'go' followed by north, south, east, or west")
print("Objective: collect the Chef's Hat, Chef's knives, Recipe, Remy, Spices, Ingredients, and go to the Dining Room")
print("type 'look' while in room and type 'get' followed by item to pick item up")

# Start the game in the Break Room
current_room = 'Break Room'

# Game loop
while True:
    print("You are in the", current_room)
    print("Inventory:", inventory)
    print("---------------------------------------------")
    move = input("Enter your move: ").lower()

    # Check if the player wants to move between rooms
    if move.startswith("go "):
        direction = move.split(" ")[1]
        if direction in rooms[current_room]:
            current_room = rooms[current_room][direction]
        else:
            print("I can't go there!")
        continue

    # Check if the player wants to pick up an item
    if move.startswith("get "):
        item = move.split(" ")[1]
        if item == room_items.get(current_room):
            inventory.append(item)
            remaining_items.remove(item)
            print("You picked up", item)
        else:
            print("That isn't here!")
        continue

    # Check if the player wants to enter the Dining Room
    if move == "Dining Room":
        if len(remaining_items) != 6:
            print("Ratatouille? They must be joking?!")
            print("Anton drops his pen in shock")
            print("This is the best ratatouille I have ever had; it brings me back to my childhood!")
            print("\nCongratulations! You completed the game!")
            print("Thank you for playing.")
        else:
            print("Ratatouille? They must be joking?!")
            print("Anton drops his pen in shock")
            print("A rat can make better ratatouille than this!")
            print("\nYou failed to impress Anton! Better luck next time.")
            print("Thank you for playing.")
        sys.exit()

        # Check if the player wants to see the description of the current room
    if move == "look":
        print("You see:", room_items.get(current_room))
        continue

    # Handle invalid input
    print("Invalid Input\n")
```

I tried using len() but could not get it to work properly and I'm not sure what's going on with the win/lose conditions

Comment: `if move == "Dining Room"` This will never be true, because moves look like "go north" or "get recipe".  I think you meant `if current_room == "Dining Room"` instead.